# Powershell to compare two columns with csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I would like to compare values in two columns in file1.csv with file2.csv, then assigned the matching value to a new column in file1.csv.

ATM, this is the working so far. Simpler format would be ideal.

```
$report = Import-CSV -Path "C:\report.csv" -Encoding UTF8
$reference = Import-CSV -Path "C:\team.csv" -Encoding UTF8

foreach ($team1 in $report){
$matched = $false
    foreach ($team2 in $reference){
    $obj = "" | select "Type","Setup","Responsible","Team","Main"
    if($team1.'Setup' -like "*$($team2.'Main')*"){
        $matchCounter++
        $matched = $true
        $obj.'Type' = $team1.'Type'
        $obj.'Setup' = $team1.'Setup'
        $obj.'Responsible' = $team1.'Responsible'
        $obj.'Team' = $team2.'Team'
        $obj | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Output.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation -Encoding 
UTF8
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the files like;

```
file1

type  setup          responsible
----  -------        -----------   
y     master fin       susan
y     sensei kuno      peter
y     sensei jon       peter
y     junior           jumo

file2

main     team
----     -----
master   sa1
sensei   sr2
jumo     st6

desired file3

type  setup       responsible  team
----  -------     -----------  -----
y     master fin     susan      sa1
y     sensei kuno    peter      sr2
y     sensei jon     peter      sr2
y     junior         jumo       st6
```

What I would like to achieve is column `setup` and `responsible` (file1) to be compared to `main` column (file2) and get its adjacent `team`. Atm, im not sure how to go about skipping cells in column1 with no reference in file2, but existed in column2. Also, to compare only the first character of `setup` in file1 with file2.

Comment: For your script, comparing the first character would be something like: `if(($team1.'Setup')[0] -eq ($team2.'Main')[0]){ ...`. In case you don't want to reinvent the wheel (also regarding performance). Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `Import-Csv .\report.csv |Join (Import-Csv .\team.csv) -on { $_.Setup[0] } -eq { $_.Main[0] } |Format-Table`

Comment: `jumo` can only be matched in the `responsible` column of file1, not in the `setup` column where the rest of the values are being matched. Please provide better examples

Comment: @iRon your first method sorted the first character issue, but atm its deleting the rows with no reference, how should i simply skip those row instead of deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you you just want to do this:

```
# $report = Import-CSV -Path "C:\report.csv" -Encoding UTF8
$report = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
type, setup,       responsible
y,    master fin,  susan
y,    sensei kuno, peter
y,    sensei jon,  peter
y,    junior,      jumo
'@

# $reference = Import-CSV -Path "C:\team.csv" -Encoding UTF8
$reference = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
main,   team
master, sa1
sensei, sr2
jumo,   st6
'@
 
foreach ($team1 in $report){
    foreach ($team2 in $reference){
        if($team1.Setup[0] -eq $team2.Main[0]){
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Type        = $team1.Type
                Setup       = $team1.Setup
                Responsible = $team1.Responsible
                Team        = $team2.Team
            }
        }
    }
} # |Export-Csv -Path .\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

**Results:**

```
Type Setup       Responsible Team
---- -----       ----------- ----
y    master fin  susan       sa1
y    sensei kuno peter       sr2
y    sensei jon  peter       sr2
y    junior      jumo        st6
```

Note that the for correctly using the [PowerShell Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) (and performance reasons), the final (`Export-Csv`) cmdlet shouldn't reside in your *process* but actually at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: its not displaying any data atm, how should i pass the backtick, in the csv data itself? any way to get reference in code itself, without altering the csv reference table?

Comment: You should just be able to paste the [mcve] above in PowerShell and get the results as shown which should give you a start for your own data. There is nothing about backticks or "*get reference in code itself*" in the original question, I suggest to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer (if the example works) and open new questions for any new question.